# Manipulate serialization result for a many=true serialization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to manipulate the serialization result of a `many=True` serialization:

```
class CustomContentElementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomContentElement
        fields = [
            'type',
            'html'
        ]

result = CustomContentElementSerializer(
    CustomContentElement.objects.all(),
    many=True
)
```

I don`t want to manipulate the single object serialization result, but the complete list. With overriding function `to_representation`, I'm just able to manipulate the single elements of the returned list.

I think it`s complicated, because the `ModelSerializer` class sets it`s base class in the constructor (Line 117: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py)

Does somebody have an idea how it could be possible to manipulate the result at the end for `many=True` serialization?

**Solution (thank you @MSR974):**

```
class CustomContentElementListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = super().to_representation(data)
        return self.manipulate_list_representation(data)

    def manipulate_list_representation(self, data):
        data.reverse()
        return data

class CustomContentElementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = FilerImageFieldSerializer()

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = CustomContentElementListSerializer
        model = CustomContentElement
        fields = [
            'type',
            'col_id',               
        ]
```

It`s in the docs at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior

Comment: What do you mean by *"manipulate"*? What do you want to do?

Comment: I need to convert it to a dict, because I need a special structure. It is not important for the question. If it is not possible in the serializer, I would do it in the view. But I think it would be cleaner to do it in the serializer.

Comment: to a dict? that doesn't make any sense since you are handling more than one model objects which do have the same keys.

Comment: I need to add some meta information. I could add it in the view, but because I need it everytime I serialize this type of data, I think it`s cleaner to have it in the serializer:
{
  "info_a": "Whatever",
  "items": [item_a, item_b, ...]
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, as expected "many" means the serialization is repeated x times with x being the number of object it has to process

You should probably go with a custom [ListSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior)